# Laravel Eloquent query on pivot table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pivot

I have the following tables in my database:

```
trips
    start - date
    end - date
    type - string

users
    name - string
    age - integer

trip_users (pivot table for many to many relationship)
    trip_id - integer
    user_id - integer
```

I want to get users with age between x-y having trips between dateA and dateB using Eloquent.

Comment: You need to show some code... We need to see your models, including the relationship between them, and the query you've attempted so far.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a [scope](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#local-scopes) or two to your model.

```php
// User.php

protected $with = ['trips'];

public function trips() {
    return $this->belongstoMany(Trip::class);
}

// scope for age
public function scopeAgeBetween($query, $age1, $age2) {
    return $query->whereBetween('age', [$age1, $age2]);
}

// scope for trip dates
public function scopeTripDatesBetween($query, $dateStart, $dateEnd) {
    return $query->whereDate('trips.start', '>=', $dateStart)
        ->whereDate('trips.end', '<=', $dateEnd);
}
```

Then in your code:

```php
User::with('trips')->ageBetween(20, 30)->tripDatesBetween('2020-01-01', '2020-02-01')->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
User::query()
->whereBetween('age', [$x, $y])
->whereHas('trips', function ($q) {
    $q->where('start', '>', $dateA)
      ->where('end', '<', $dateB)
})
->get();
```